# Momentjs strict format always returns 'Invalid date'

Tags: javascript, momentjs

According to momentjs docs `toJSON()` produces ISO 8601 formatted string and `moment.defaultFormat` is ISO 8601 format.

Taking this in account I would expect to get a valid date, but

```js
moment(moment().toJSON(), moment.defaultFormat, true).toString()
```

always returns 'Invalid Date'.

Comment: Does the defaultFormat match your json string?

Comment: it works for momentjs v2.2.1, not working for later version http://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/a6afq07y/

Comment: @DanielH you are using an old version of momentjs in your fiddle

Comment: @VincenzoC, yes it is not working after v2.2.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right, [`moment().toJSON()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-json/) returns an ISO 8601 format, but is not the same of [`moment.defaultFormat`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#default-format).

The issue is that `moment().toJSON()` includes fractional seconds (`SSS` token) that are not part of `moment.defaultFormat` (that is `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ`).

`moment().toJSON()` output can be parsed:

- Using [`moment(String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/)
- Using [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) passing [`moment.ISO_8601`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/special-formats/) as format parameter
- Providing a format string that matches with `toJSON()` output (`'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ'`)

Here a live sample:

```js
console.log( moment(moment().toJSON(), moment.defaultFormat, true).toString()  );

console.log( moment().toJSON() );
console.log( moment.defaultFormat );

console.log( moment(moment().toJSON(), 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ', true).toString()  );

console.log( moment(moment().toJSON(), moment.ISO_8601, true).toString()  );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```